# Alexa call custom intent without "ask" the skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I would like to call my utterances without saying **ask + InvocationName**.
By example:

> Alexa, what is my plan today ?

Instead of

> Alexa, **ask my planning** what is my plan today ?

I was thinking that you need to launch your skill (**Alexa, launch my planning**)
and set **shouldEndSession** to **false**, but it's not working, do i do it wrong ?

I found "canfulfillintentrequest" explaning [here](https://developer.amazon.com/fr/docs/custom-skills/implement-canfulfillintentrequest-for-name-free-interaction.html) but i'm not able to turn on it on dev alexa panel :/

So, i'm stuck and not sure if it's really possible ?

Thanks by advance for the answer.

Comment: Probably not want you're looking for but SmartHome skills allow for name free interaction "eg. alexa turn on my device"

Comment: I'm looking for a custom skills but thanks for the info :/

Answer (score 4):

`canfulfillintentrequest` is exactly what you want if you are looking for **name-free interactions** to interact with Alexa without invoking a specific skill by its invocation name.

**How CanFulfillIntentRequest works:**

1. The customer speaks to Alexa with a requested action, a question, or a statement that does not include a skill name.
2. Alexa, process this utterance and queries few skills which can handle `CanFulfillIntentRequest` to check whether they can fulfill the request.
3. Your skill receive a `CanFulfillIntentRequest` with the processed utterances and slots. Your skills has to then respond back with a `canFulfillIntent` object that contains the mandatory field `canFulfill` for the intent, and two optional fields for slot– `canUnderstand` and `canFulfill`.
4. Alexa collects the responses from the original list of skills and select the best skill to fulfill the customer's request.
5. Alexa calls the selected skill with an actual `IntentRequest`, just like how a customer might have invoked the skill by name. Your skill has to then respond back to this `IntentRequest` as usual.

If your skill supports the `CanFulfillIntentRequest` interface, then your skill may be chosen and auto-enabled to fulfill a query for users who have not enabled your skill yet.

---

`shouldEndSession` property is used to keep-alive a skill session (when you want a response from the user) for a max time of 8 seconds followed by `reprompt` and another 8 seconds. You cannot extend this time. While you are in an active session you don't have to use invocation name.

> **Note:** The use of `CanFulfillIntentRequest` in Alexa skills is offered as a public preview/beta and may improve or change. This
>   feature is available for English (U.S.) skills only.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's exactly what i'm looking for, unfortunatelyi'm french: / But maybe a tricks existing or an other solution? Because Skills like Spotify or Uber... are using it